After integrating Auth0 with Angular, login and logout are not working
I have an Angular project using version 17. I'm trying to connect Auth0 login to it. When I click the login button in the Angular app, it navigates me to the Auth0 login window. After logging in, the app still displays the login button instead of the logout button. It seems the value of "auth.isAuthenticated$ | async" is not changing.
I've attached my code. Can you help me figure out what's going wrong?
app.component.html
<ng-container *ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated$ | async; else loggedOut">
    <button (click)="auth.logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: document.location.origin } })" class="h-[60px] w-[200px] bg-primary-bg text-secondary">
  Log out
    </button>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loggedOut>
    <button (click)="auth.loginWithRedirect()" class="h-[60px] w-[200px] bg-primary-bg text-secondary">Log in</button>
</ng-template>

app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet, RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AuthModule, AuthService } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';
import { AuthButtonComponent } from './auth-button/auth-button.component';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    AsyncPipe,
    AuthButtonComponent,
    CommonModule,
    RouterOutlet,
    RouterLink,
    ReportsComponent,
    AddDomainsComponent,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent{

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) public document: Document, public auth: AuthService){}

}

app.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import {provideHttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';


export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideAuth0({
      domain: '',
      clientId: '',
      authorizationParams: {
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin
      }
    }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(),
  ]
};

app.routes.ts
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ReportsComponent } from './reports/reports.component';
import { AddDomainsComponent } from './add-domains/add-domains.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {path:'reports', component:ReportsComponent},
    {path:'add-domains', component:AddDomainsComponent},
    {path:'', redirectTo:'/reports', pathMatch:'full'},
    {path:'**', redirectTo:'/reports'},
];

